# not able to pass data to a data object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

N.B: I'm pretty much new to angularJS programming. What I'm trying to do is, to save info returned by a service to an object. My object looks like this.

```
var userObject = {
                    "id": "1",
                    "firstName": "Amelia",
                    "lastName": "Earheart"
                };
```

I have a factory that returns data from back end and it looks like this:

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {
            var baseUrl = 'backendservice/';

            return {
                myInfo:function() {
                    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getmyInfo');
                }
            };
        })
```

And this is how my Controller communicates with the factory service:

```
    .controller('myController', function($routeParams,myService) {
        var my = this;

        my.basicInfo = function () {
                //to get my info
                myService.myInfo().success(function(data) {
                    my.activeUser.myData.id             = data.id;
                    my.activeUser.myData.firstName  = data.firstName;
                    my.activeUser.myData.lastName   = data.lastName;
                }); 
        };


        my.addSomething = function(post) {
            var userObject = my.basicInfo();

        };

    });
```

and this is how I assign the data to `userObject`

```
var userObject = my.basicInfo();
```

I don't know why it's not working. Factory service runs but the value is not assigned to userObject.

My Controller as whole looks like this:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('myApp.spa', [])

        .factory('myService', function($http) {
            var baseUrl = 'backendservice/';

            return {
                myInfo:function() {
                    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getmyInfo');
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('myController', function($routeParams,myService) {
            var my = this;

            my.basicInfo = function () {
                    //to get my info
                    myService.myInfo().success(function(data) {
                        my.activeUser.myData.id             = data.id;
                        my.activeUser.myData.firstName  = data.firstName;
                        my.activeUser.myData.lastName   = data.lastName;
                    }); 
            };


            my.addSomething = function(post) {
                var userObject = my.basicInfo();

            };

        });         
})();
```

Comment: you define your variable inside the function: 
            my.addSomething = function(post) {
                var userObject = my.basicInfo();

            }; it will not be accessible from the outside

Comment: `my.activeUser.myData.id` where is this defined? This should be throwing error based on the shared code.

Comment: `var userObject = my.basicInfo();`, but `basicInfo` does return nothing

Comment: Is the service returning data? try putting console.log(data) and check it on browser console if it prints something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is my.basicInfo does not return anything and also from $http.success/failure, you can not return any value. 
So in this case, following steps you would have to do:

1. Define var userObject at the top of your controller so that can be accessible to all the methods.
2. Assign data to userObject inside success callback of $http

   ```
   (function() {
   angular
       .module('myApp.spa', [])

       .factory('myService', function($http) {
           var baseUrl = 'backendservice/';

           return {
               myInfo:function() {
                   return $http.get(baseUrl + 'getmyInfo');
               }
           };
       })

       .controller('myController', function($routeParams,myService) {
           var my = this;
           var userObject;

           my.basicInfo = function () {
                   //to get my info
                   myService.myInfo().success(function(data) {
                       my.activeUser.myData.id             = data.id;
                       my.activeUser.myData.firstName  = data.firstName;
                       my.activeUser.myData.lastName   = data.lastName;

                       userObject = data;
                   }); 
           };


           my.addSomething = function(post) {
               my.basicInfo();

           };

       });         
   })();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Your function `my.basicInfo()` does not return anything so the value of your variable `userObject` is `undefined`. Also if you want to use `userObject` on view expose it on your controller instance as `my.userObject`.

If you want to assign a value to `userObject`, do it either within the `success` callback of `my.basicInfo()` method or return a promise from the method `my.basicInfo()` and assign the value in `then` callback of the promise

**Approach 1**

```
    my.basicInfo = function () {
            //to get my info
            var activeUser = {};
            return myService.myInfo()
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.extend(activeUser, response.data);
                my.userObject = activeUser;
            }); 
    };
```

**Approach 2**

```
    my.basicInfo = function () {
            //to get my info
            var activeUser = {};
            return myService.myInfo()
            .then(function(data) {
                angular.extend(activeUser, response.data);
                return activeUser;
            }); 
    };

    my.addSomething = function(post) {
        my.basicInfo()
         .then(function (response) {
           my.userObject = response;
         });
    };
```

Comment: `activeUser.myData.id ` and everything else will throw error since `myData` is undefined.

Comment: missed return of promise in both cases.

Comment: @vp_arth Done. Fixed it to return promise

Comment: @TJ Added the attribute `myData` on the `activeUser` object to fix the error

Comment: @AdityaSingh it's better to have it as part of the object literal `activeUser` since adding properties later for no specific reason is a performance hit. Secondly, the actual result of `http` request will be inside a `data` property of  response, which is named `data` as well in this code, so I believe it should be `data.data.id` and so on

Comment: Any of it is fine. I just didn't want to modify that part of OP's code. :)

Comment: @AdityaSingh see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. `data.id`, `data.firstName` etc will be undefined...

Answer (score -1):

```
.factory('UserInfo', function($resource, apiHost) {
  return $resource(apiHost + '/userinfo/:userId'); 
});


.controller('myController', function($routeParams,UserInfo) {
        var vm = this;
        // suppose that you have stored the userId somewhere after the login
        vm.userObject = {};
        var myUserInfo = UserInfo.get({
                userId: userId
            });



             vm.refreshData = function (){
              myUserInfo.$promise
                .then(function(response) {
                 vm.userObject = response;

                }, function(error) {

                    // doSomething
                });
              };

            vm.update = function(){
               myUserInfo.save(vm.userObject, function() {
                // console.log('success');

               }, function(error) {
                // console.log('error');

              });


        };

    });
```

Comment: You can't to return from nested asynchronous calls

Comment: This is wrong. Your code will still have the same result because the function `basicInfo` doesn't return anything